# My bounty is expiring with no new answers or comments; how else can I draw attention to it?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have [a bounty with an upcoming expiration deadline](https://superuser.com/q/876912/199803).

There were no comments, answers, or even votes on this question prior to placing the bounty. There are still no comments, answers, or votes. The problem described in the question is an ongoing hassle in my daily work, and I'd really like a solution, but I don't have enough rep (just over 200 points left) to feel comfortable risking even more of it.

Obviously, I am hoping that by posting about it here, I might draw some more attention to it, but I would have expected the bounty to do a better job of attracting eyeballs in the first place, so I guess we'll see.

Comment: Tangentially, any guesses on why no one has offered any thoughts on the original question? Is it just that the question is too long/complicated/setup-specific?

Comment: Its super esoteric, and involves a very specific set of software an virtual hardware with an unusual window manager. I've had no answers on a similar question on real hardware and worked it out myself. Posting a comment on some troubleshooting steps.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that the question is way too long, and the last couple of sections have too many aspects.  If it takes that much information for someone to figure out what the problem is, this may not be the best venue for an answer.  Xrandr is not a real popular topic and many of the other questions about it have also gone unanswered.